# Wordpress HTML custom tag not working when I click "post"

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I'm trying to add some custom html code to a Wordpress post in order to be able to add a small javascript "program" that let's you change a square's color depending on a value you enter.

The code is html with **style** and **script** tags. It works correctly when tested on my computer and when I click the "Preview" button on the HTML custom tag. However, once I post the post it breaks and shows the entire code as text. Is there a way I can make it work? I've been watching videos and reading about how to fix this, but I can't find a solution!

Thank you for your time!!

Comment: Try with the following plugin to add the custom css and javascirpt codes.
Plugin URL: https://wordpress.org/plugins/header-and-footer-scripts/

Comment: If you did copy paste of your local code inside the text editor of the WordPress, then will no work for sure. WordPress comes with a special filter called [kses](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_kses/) which is responsible to filter our unwanted code from posts / comments / etc. This filter exists to protect your site from XSS attacks. Thus it seems like your code is break because of that filter. The way you can integrate your code, is to either create a shortcode that includes your code or embed your javascript / css into your theme and apply the html only in the editor